# Is there a Unity equivalent of the GNOME panel 'show desktop' applet?

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a “Show desktop” icon to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126540/how-to-add-a-show-desktop-icon-to-the-launcher)

I miss the symbol to show the desktop with just one click when using Unity instead of the classic desktop.

Is there a possibility to get the "Show Desktop" applet or an equivalent?  There is a bug report on:

- [Bug #681348](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/681348) *("Add 'show me the desktop' keyboard or Unity dock shortcut")*

Can people suggest any workarounds in the mean-time?