# Why did show desktop icon go away and how do I get it back?

Tags: unity, 11.10, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Unity equivalent of the GNOME panel 'show desktop' applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-unity-equivalent-of-the-gnome-panel-show-desktop-applet)

So first the rant..

I don't understand how you can release an operating system without a show desktop icon installed by default. It is extremely annoying to a lot of users, especially new Ubuntu adopters. I honestly hadn't noticed since I use the keyboard shortcut (which also keeps being switched between super+D and alt+ctrl+D) but people I have convinced to use ubuntu are really pissed off since they have to minimize all the windows to access the desktop - and I can understand them. And no, they are not interested in keyboard shortcuts they will not remember.

That being said the worst thing seems to be there is no fix for this that I can find! Webupd8 posted the [following post](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/show-desktop-icon-for-ubuntu-unity.html). The solution that's suggested there is quite frankly worse than nothing for people without the ability to middle click (many mice/keyboard doesn't have a middle button). I was so frustrated with it I deleted it after a few days. It's not only the 10 second wait, even after waiting it doesn't work properly.

Any ideas on how to win this confidence back from new Ubuntu users?

Comment: I find the way you are asking this question a bit sensational, and only slightly removed from rants I heard from a small subset of Indian users saying that nobody in the entire country of India will use an OS without a "refresh desktop" in the right-click menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> under 11.10, Show desktop is the leftmost icon. If you don't want to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go backwards, you can release <kbd>Tab</kbd> and use the arrow keys while still holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

As is noted by ImaginaryRobots on [Is there a Unity equivalent of the GNOME panel 'show desktop' applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-unity-equivalent-of-the-gnome-panel-show-desktop-applet), a 'Show desktop' icon is shown when pressing (and holding) Alt+Tab. Surely, anybody knows that key combination? Of course, if the user isn't used to that key combination, he/she will have a hard time then holding Alt and keep pressing Tab until 'Show Desktop' is highlighted.

So I agree that it's at least awkward that such a simple icon has been removed AND that the key combination Super+D has been replaced. Worthy of a new papercut bug IMHO...

Comment: After having tried the show desktop icon in the alt-tab view for a while I must say I find it a little frustrating to use when you have 10 windows open. Also, for people used to navigating by pointing and clicking, it doesn't really work.