# Simple launcher to minimize all windows?

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Unity equivalent of the GNOME panel 'show desktop' applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-unity-equivalent-of-the-gnome-panel-show-desktop-applet)

Is there a simple way to create a launcher for Unity that minimizes all windows or, ideally, toggles (e.g., like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)? If so, what is it?