# xubuntu 14.04 change "minimize all windows" (show desktop)

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, navigation

None of the suggested answers:

> [How to change de "Minimize all windows" shortcut in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165068/how-to-change-de-minimize-all-windows-shortcut-in-xubuntu)
>   [Simple launcher to minimize all windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68988/simple-launcher-to-minimize-all-windows)\
>   [Is there a keybind to minimize all windows, without a toggle?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13709/is-there-a-keybind-to-minimize-all-windows-without-a-toggle)
>   ... answer the question, although moderators happily closed the questions with the comment "question was answered in ..." and refer to an earlier answer.

Well, we're talking about xubuntu, not ubuntu. And we're talking about xubuntu 14.04, not earlier editions.  In 14.04 the system settings > keyboard app has no "navigation" tab, and I can't find any screen or input page that mentions Ctrl-Alt-d; althnough the answers above do suggest it.  I tried it, and it works in 14.04.

So the question still is:  How to put this Ctrl-Alt-D key sequence in a launcher which can be pinned to the panel, and what I want to know is... where is there a listing of all these keyboard gimmicks?

Thanks

Comment: please can anyone who HAS the show desktop option in their keyboard settings please paste the command that's used, so I/we can manually add this? It's missing for me too (fresh 15.04 install)

Answer (score 14):

The shortcut for "Show Desktop" is in the Window-Manager-Menu.

**`Settings  →  Window Manager  →  Keyboard`**

There you will find **`Show Desktop : Ctrl + Alt + D`** and you can change it to whatever you wish.

Comment: If your xfce settings get boinked, you can manually see and edit this setting (and others you can't even see in the standard settings- at your own risk) with the settings editor 
xfce4-settings-editor

It is stored under xfce-keyboard-shortcuts. This is the only way to change some of the preassigned keyboard shortcuts (printscreen for print... a mac keyboard does not HAVE printscreen)

This works for xubuntu 8.04 + 16.10 as an alternative... and is faster IMO

Answer (score 4):

You can also add the show desktop icon **to the panel** in Xubuntu (tested in 16.04, but I'm hoping it works in 14.04 too), as follows:

- Right-click an empty space on the panel
- Choose *Panel → Add New Items...*
- Search for *Show desktop*
- Select it and click *Add*

Now you have the show desktop icon to click on. I like to right click it and go to *Move*, then I move it to the far left next to my start menu icon.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please, [do not overuse bold](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15446/lets-agree-on-some-commonly-accepted-formatting-guidelines). :) I tweaked the formatting a bit.

Answer (score 0):

**XUBUNTU 18.04**

Search for the **Show Desktop** option in keyboard shortcuts settings. You can see other shortcuts here and edit them.

[image: Window Manger settings]

Comment: Well, the command is Super+D.

Comment: The command is <super>+d (in linuxmint)

Comment: Well pointed out @Harryg123. I've added the linux distro I am in. But I assumed the visitors of this issue would be Xubuntu ones given its title.

Comment: huh? I asked this question years ago when i was experimenting, trying to decide which distro to use.  Now I have a new question:  How can I set askubuntu.com to stop sending me email notifications regarding this topic?