# Where is showdesktop button on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Unity equivalent of the GNOME panel 'show desktop' applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29969/is-there-a-unity-equivalent-of-the-gnome-panel-show-desktop-applet)

I understand that alt-ctrl-d will show the desktop in Unity 2D, but is there a button that will do the same thing for when my hands aren't on the keyboard?

I saw Unity 3D had it as a choice in the app switcher, but Unity 2D does not.

Comment: For those who use gnome-session-fallback the 'Show Sesktop' icon can be added back to gnome-panel

Comment: @Anonymous The question is how