# Is there a fast way to show your desktop

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Unity’s keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)

I need to see content on my desktop or a folder just pressing an icon or a couple of keys. 
How i do this on unity?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 32):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 you can simply hit **Ctrl + Super + D** to minimize all windows. Super key is also known as the Windows key.

Another tip, holding the super key in Ubuntu 12.04 will bring up a list of shortcuts for your future use.

Comment: I like the Ctrl + Super + D way. It's helpful for those running Unity 2D because the Alt + Tab switcher **doesn't** show the desktop as an option in Unity 2D mode whereas it does in Unity 3D mode.

Comment: You don't need to use Ctrl anymore. Super + D works fine.

Answer (score 7):

You can access desktop just by a movement of mouse...!

Follow these steps to set it up!

**Install Ubuntu Tweak:**

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal and run the following commands one by one.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Press Super key (Windows key) to open the dash and search for "Ubuntu Tweak" and open it.

[image]

**Configuration:**

Click on the "Tweaks" tab of Ubuntu Tweak (2nd tab from left) and select workspace.

[image]

Hare you can bind four action to four corners of your screen. Just click on the drop down menu of any four of them and select `show desktop`.

[image]

That's it. Now just move your cursor to the corner you just have set to `show desktop`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu 12.04.

**You can use the Alt + Tab switcher to show the desktop , like in the image below:**

[image]

Also, [you can add "Show Desktop" icon to the launcher.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126540/how-to-add-a-show-desktop-icon-to-the-launcher)

Answer (score 3):

There is also a very practical way to show desktop in Ubuntu 12.04 known as a "hot corner" available in CompizConfig Settings Manger. You can only move the mouse cursor to the selected corner and desktop will be displayed.

Almost all ways for showing desktop in Ubuntu 12.04 are described in the article: http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/show-desktop-in-ubuntu-12-04/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using MyUnity, just go to the Desktop tab and activate Show desktop icon.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you'd loose some words about MyUnity, though it is not installed by default.