# How to minimize all windows and go to the desktop using mouse on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: windows, mouse, shortcuts

Is there a way to see the desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 without using the keyboard when many windows are open? Like in Windows you just have to hover over the bottom right of the screen to view it and by clicking it you can go to the desktop.

What I mean is I want to be able to get access to the desktop even when there are multiple windows open with just a hover. I found an extension but it requires clicking a button.

Comment: Do you have workspaces enabled? Please [edit] you question to make it clear what you have tried and what it is you are actually seeking to achieve. If you have (say) Chrome or Firefox open, click on the minimise button (top right hand side of the window) and it will be minimised to the left menu bar.

Comment: @User24601 Read method 1 in [this website](https://easykey.uk/windows/3-quick-ways-to-show-the-desktop) to understand what Akshay Alva is trying to say.

Comment: @User24601 I have made changes to my original question and have removed my second query as I was able to do it with the 'Dash to Dock' extension.

Comment: @technastic_tc Yes that's right.

Comment: @AkshayAlva Perhaps answer you own question then [answer]

Comment: I hope this can be useful to you: https://askubuntu.com/a/132171/1103140 but this method might be outdated..

Comment: Are you using GNOME or Unity?

Comment: @technastic_tc yeah it's outdated....I'm using Gnome

Comment: I hope this website will be useful: https://codepre.com/how-to-set-hot-corners-in-ubuntu-20-04-gnome-shell.html

Comment: @technastic_tc yeah I've got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: I hope you got what you wanted. Please do post an answer to your question. It'll be helpful to the community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'CustomCorner' extension to apply hotkeys to all 4 corners of the screen

Comment: Hey Akshay Alva! It would be great if your answer is more detailed.