# Show Desktop in ubuntu launcher

Tags: launcher, show-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a “Show desktop” icon to the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126540/how-to-add-a-show-desktop-icon-to-the-launcher)

I have a problem in show desktop in the Unity launcher (Ubuntu 12.04)
I had activated through Myunity than I moved it to the top of the launcher (as in this image)

[image]

but today I made an update and the icon become a part of the launcher (in the bottom) as in the image

[image]

and I can't move it to the top ,

Please Help me a need it in the top because when I open a lot of app it'll be hidden and hard to find.

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/128502/can-i-move-the-show-desktop-button and here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126540/how-to-add-a-show-desktop-icon-to-the-launcher

Comment: I can't solve your issue, but just suggest you to use `ctrl+alt+d` to minimize all windows and showing your desktop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The location of "Show Desktop" icon has been a controversial one.
Current scenario:
"Show Desktop" icon can be enabled by using myunity or ccsm and is placed at the bottom of the launcher.You can NOT change it's position in the launcher.
According to the progress on this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/681348),we will soon see a "mini-app" that will do the same function as "Show Desktop",but it's position in the Launcher can be changed by dragging and dropping.

### For Ubuntu 12.10

This issue has been resolved in Ubuntu 12.10, where you can change the position of "Show Desktop" icon by dragging and dropping.