# Recommended ways to add mouse control of minimise windows Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, compiz, mouse

I've recently switched from Windows XP to Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm happy using Ubuntu, with one small exception.

I've been unable to work out how to minimise windows using the mouse and the launch pad, and after coming from Win XP I really miss the task-bar icon to show or hide the desk top.

Looking on the internet I've found CompizConfig, but I've also found dire warnings that it can seriously damage your system.

So what is the best way to add the option of minimising a window and show desktop using the mouse?

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with the normal close, minimize, maximize buttons? And what is the "launch pad"?

Comment: Posibally "minimize on click" which is in compizconfig(which is in it's self in not nessarly dangerous - but all the desktop breaking settings you might configure)

Comment: And: http://askubuntu.com/a/269097/47291

Comment: Also please ask one question at a time.

Comment: So you want a shortcut you can click on to minimize everything and return to a blank desktop?